# Group element in list based on conditions and indexes

Tags: python

I have a set of lists composed of names and role. However, there is no real logic between how the list are organized.

For instance, I have this list :

```
l = ['john', 'owner', 'mark', 'manager', 'alex', 'steve', 'employee', 'manager'] #the last role shouldn't be assigned to anyone
```

I want to assign each person the role that is located next to it in the list or the closest one from left to right.

The desired output should be something like :

```
output = [['john', 'owner'], ['mark', 'manager'], ['alex', 'employee'], ['steve', 'employee']]
```

My guess was to add indexes to the list elements, and than check which element based on a set of condition was closest to the list element I was looking at.

This is part of my script :

```
parties_role = [(idx, item) for idx,item in enumerate(l)]
    for item in parties_role:
        if "owner" not in str(item[1]) and 'manager' not in str(item[1]) and 'employee' not in str(item[1]):
        name = str(item[1])
```

The rest of the code shoud look at the list items that contain the keywords `owner`, `manager` and `employee` and assign to the current `name` variable the closest role based on the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple loop on the reversed input, you can assign the role that is immediately after one or several names:

```
roles = {'owner', 'manager', 'employee'}

result = []
role = None
for x in reversed(l):
    if x in roles:
        role = x
        continue
    result.append([x, role])

# if order is important
result = result[::-1]
```

Output:

```
[['john', 'owner'],
 ['mark', 'manager'],
 ['alex', 'employee'],
 ['steve', 'employee'],
]
```

Comment: Try testing this with a trailing name. E.g. `l = ['john', 'owner', 'mark', 'manager', 'alex', 'steve', 'employee', 'manager', 'bob']`. You'll get a `['bob', None]` in the results. You could `if role: result.append([x, role])`

Comment: @Chris yes it's on purpose. You can choose either to remove this name or to set up a default like I did. Depends on the expected behavior. Given OPs example, it could also never happen.

Answer (score 1):

Let's create a set of "roles":

```
roles = {'owner', 'manager', 'employee'}
```

Now, let's use `reduce`. Our accumulator is a tuple with two lists: the final result and the second list is a "bucket" of names read thus far. When it encounters a role, it maps those names to that role and adds them to the  result list.

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> grouped = reduce(
...   lambda acc, x: 
...     (acc[0] + [[y, x] for y in acc[1]], []) if x in roles else 
...     (acc[0], acc[1] + [x]), 
...   l, 
...   ([], [])
... )
>>> grouped[0]
[['john', 'owner'], ['mark', 'manager'], ['alex', 'employee'], ['steve', 'employee']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could start with a set of known roles...you need *some* way to tell names from roles, so I assume this is possible. With that you can group by whether the string is a name or a role. This should give you alternating groups of names and roles. Then zip and assemble:

```
from itertools import groupby

roles = {'owner', 'manager', 'employee'}    
l = ['john', 'owner', 'mark', 'manager', 'alex', 'steve', 'employee', 'manager']

groups = (list(v) for _, v in groupby(l, key=lambda s: s in roles))
result = [[name, roles[0]] for names, roles in zip(groups, groups) for name in names]
```

This produces a `result` of:

```
[['john', 'owner'],
 ['mark', 'manager'],
 ['alex', 'employee'],
 ['steve', 'employee']]
```

It makes the assumption that the original list starts with a name.

Answer (score 1):

I might do it like this:

- Define which strings are roles and which aren't (e.g. create a set of valid `roles`, assume everything else is a name).
- Iterate over each `name` in `l`, using `enumerate` to track the index.

  - For each `name`, find the `next` element in `l` (after the name's index) that's a role.

```
>>> l = ['john', 'owner', 'mark', 'manager', 'alex', 'steve', 'employee', 'manager']
>>> roles = {'owner', 'manager', 'employee'}
>>> [[name, next(e for e in l[i:] if e in roles)] for i, name in enumerate(l) if name not in roles]
[['john', 'owner'], ['mark', 'manager'], ['alex', 'employee'], ['steve', 'employee']]
```